# Seems simple div class element but selenium cant click

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Seems simple div class element but selenium cant click

Below is credential in code

Uid:-wealthytarundas2015@gmail.com

pwd:-Tapan@321

```
            package basic.basic;

            import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

            import org.openqa.selenium.By;
            import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
            import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
            import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

            public class Add {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            // 

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://Sprints//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
                     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                 driver.get("http://addmefast.com//");

                 driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("wealthytarundas2015@gmail.com");

                 driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Tapan@321");

                 driver.findElement(By.name("login_button")).click();
                 Thread.sleep(4000);   

                 driver.findElement(By.linkText("YouTube Likes")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
                 Thread.sleep(6000);
                 driver.findElement(By.className("btn3")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN); //CODE TO CLICK LINK buttton but getting error here



            }

            }
```

Error in eclipse console:-

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a) on port 10411
Only local connections are allowed.
Oct 03, 2017 11:55:38 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

Comment: Here is the HTML                                                                                                                                      
                         <a class="single_like_button btn3-wrap" 
                        onclick="openFbLWin_3764067();">
   <span>&nbsp;</span><div class="btn3">Like</div></a>

Comment: Please take a few minutes to properly format your question so that it's more readable, especially the code indent, etc. You also should edit the question and place the HTML inside rather than in a comment so it's easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

I introduced Explicit wait(for the 'link' button to appear in the page) to the code and I was able to locate 'like' button and click it.

Try the below code and let me know if it works for you.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Add {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://Sprints//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("http://addmefast.com//");
      driver. manage(). window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("wealthytarundas2015@gmail.com");
      driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Tapan@321");
      driver.findElement(By.name("login_button")).click();
      Thread.sleep(4000);
      driver.findElement(By.linkText("YouTube Likes")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
      Thread.sleep(6000);
      WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
      WebElement like;
      like= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("btn3")));
        like.click();
    }
}
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score -1):

I think you cannot click the div "btn3" because it is inside the link.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("btn3")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Try the following to make it work:

Update:

```
driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("div#likedPagesSingle a"));
```

Comment: I can almost guarantee this is not going to work! A space is not a valid character for a class name. In the HTML, the class attribute is a space-separated **list** of class names.

Comment: @koen Meijer i tried now ,got below error Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

Comment: You're right. That will not work, I looked at the website and you can use a css selector to find the link. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just got it working ,thanks for reply `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class = 'single_like_button btn3-wrap']/div[@class = 'btn3']")));`